# pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm getting an error every time I try to use pyautogui.

Here's the code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\PycharmProjects\first_program\chess.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1747, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel(
  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 144, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

I've tried changing the location of install and still same error.
I've tried installing pillow

Comment: Have you tried installing pillow? https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

> pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: I just tried now it didn't work but thank you for trying

Comment: @Havissh make sure you are saving to the right python version. Try adding your python version to the command. Like `pip3.10 install pillow`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.2.0)

Comment: tried.............

Comment: @Havissh try `pip install Pillow --upgrade`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.2.0)

Comment: just tried.....